# Solaris (SPARC) to Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, google-compute-engine, solaris, sparc

How can we move Solaris (SPARC Cluster) from On-Prem to GCP Compute Engine? Does Velostrata supports migration from Solaris?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't. GCP support only x86 platform and you use Sparc. If you check the [supported OS](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/reference/supported-os-versions) for Velostrata you will see even Solaris x86 is not supported, only Windows and Linux

Comment: Thanks, Romeo. So I will be doing an endian conversion first followed by the migration

Comment: @Sid, not only. You should translate SPARC instructions to x86. And change library calls because of ABI